# Wrong design of my entity models or I am doing it wrong?

Tags: database, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

in my Winform Application, I have `Suppliers`, `Customers`, `Transport Companies`. They are similar as they are basically some kind of `Contacts`, however they do different slightly in term of available fields.

For example `Suppliers` need have `StartDate` and `EndDate` fields. And currently even though `Suppliers` and `Customers` could have more than one contact person\entity, but we are not going do that in these release, but the `Transport companies` will have more than one contact person\entity and addresses. At the same time, the `Supplier` and `Customer` do require PO Address and Delivery Address, and two phone numbers just in case.

Currently in my Code First Entities, I have `Suppliers`, `Customers` and `Transport Companies` each contains a `PrimaryContact` which is a `Contact` Type, and for each `Contact` type, I have a `ICollection` of `Address` and `Phone` which in turn store one or more than one address and phone information. The difference is that `Transport Companies` will have a collection of `Contact` in addition of `PrimaryContact`.

As my understanding, even I have the freedom of design the DB/Entity by myself, there is not always the case that Objects in BLL is exactly mapping of the DB structure underneath.
So the idea is in my BLL layer, I will translate the data from `Supplier` to `BOSupplier` to Presentation Layer, and will doing translation to `Supplier` when get data back from Presentation Layer to DAL. Because in my `Presentation` Layer, the `Supplier` will looks like:

```
    public class BOSupplier
    {
        // Primery key
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string TaxNumber { get; set; }

        public bool InActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountName { get; set; }

        // Property related to Contact Table
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string SkypeName { get; set; }

        // Proterty related to Address Table
        // PO address Info
        public string POAddressLine { get; set; }     
        public string POCity { get; set; }
        public string PORegion { get; set; }
        public string POCountry { get; set; }
        public string POPostCode { get; set; }

        // Delivery AddressLine
        public string DelAddressLine { get; set; }
        public string DelCity { get; set; }
        public string DelRegion { get; set; }
        public string DelCountry { get; set; }
        public string DelPostCode { get; set; }


        // Proterties related to Phone table
        public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But in my DAL Layer, my `Supplier` will looks like this:

```
public class Supplier
{
    // Primery key
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }

    public bool InActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I am actually writing code for BLL classes to manage my intermediate `BOSupplier` object and List which didn't actually mapping back an Entity to DB side. It seems a lots low level code just to transfer/map fields from two slightly different `BOSupplier` and `Supplier`, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<BOSupplier> GetBOSuppliers()
{
    var suppliers = dbContext.Suppliers;
    BOSupplier currentSupplier;

    foreach (Supplier supplier in suppliers)
    {
        currentSupplier = new BOSupplier()
        {
            ID = supplier.ID,
            Name = supplier.Name,
            Code = supplier.Code,
            FirstName = supplier.PrimaryContact.FirstName,
            TaxNumber = supplier.TaxNumber
        };

        // PO Address
        Address poAddress = supplier.PrimaryContact.Addresses
            .FirstOrDefault<Address>(a => a.AddressTypeValue == (int)AddressTypes.Postal);
        if (poAddress != null)
        {
            currentSupplier.POAddressLine = poAddress.AddressLine1;
            currentSupplier.POCity = poAddress.City;
            currentSupplier.POCountry = poAddress.Country;
        }

        // Delivery Address
        Address delAddress = supplier.PrimaryContact.Addresses
            .FirstOrDefault<Address>(a => a.AddressTypeValue == (int)AddressTypes.Delivery);
        if (delAddress != null)
        {
            currentSupplier.DelAddressLine = delAddress.AddressLine1;
            currentSupplier.DelCity = delAddress.City;
            currentSupplier.DelCountry = delAddress.Country;
        }

        // ToDo: 
        // There is probably more to think about how we want map multi phone numbers into limited two phone numbers
        if (supplier.PrimaryContact.Phones.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Phone phone in supplier.PrimaryContact.Phones)
            {
                if (phone.PhoneType == PhoneTypes.Default)
                {
                    currentSupplier.PhoneNumber1 = phone.PhoneNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentSupplier.PhoneNumber2 = phone.PhoneNumber;
                }
            }
        }

        this.boSupplierList.Add(currentSupplier);
    }
    return boSupplierList;
}
```

I am keep thinking: "Maybe my Entity Model should be simpler, or there is some better way of doing what I am trying to?". So please, from your experience, tell me that my Entity model are on over-complex side, or I just need some better way of mapping from `BOSuppier` to `Supplier` or some other thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity model is not complex according to your description of the domain. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map your `Supplier` to `BOSupplier`. Here is an [example](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening) of flattening object graph using AutoMapper.

I see a problem in your `GetBOSuppliers()`. It uses lazy loading when you access `PrimaryContact` and `Addresses`. To avoid the multiple round trips to database you can eager load them as follows.

```
var suppliers = dbContext.Suppliers.Include(s => s.PrimaryContact.Addresses);
```

Comment: thank you for the comments. Yes I agree that the structure is not that complex. but I am kind of not sure whether I should spend time writing this low level mapping code, or much better, using a mapper for doing that for me. But still, another option is not trying to normalize the Contact table but using a flat Model/Table instead. The Application I am writing is a Stock tracking System, and it is much more than flexible contact list.

Comment: @pstar if this type of queries are common you may de-normalize the data. Another option would be to create a view and query that using a micro ORM.

Comment: What if I want eager loading both PrimaryContact SecondaryContact?

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed trivial, I sort it out myself:D And thank you Eranga for point out AutoMapper, I looked the tutorial, and after watch the video, very interesting. I am going to us slightly flatter tables for Supplier and Customer for now, and looking forward to use AutoMapper for Fright Carrier.